# Finding two vectors in a tetrahedron

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

The question:

> Consider the tetrahedron with vertices $(0, 0, 0)$, $(a, 0, 0)$, $(0,
> b, 0)$, and ($0, 0 ,c)$ and let $S$ be the side of the tetrahedron
>   with vertices $(a, 0, 0)$, $(0, b, 0)$, and $(0, 0, c)$. By finding 2
>   vectors in $S$, find a unit normal to $S$.

I know how to find a unit normal given two vectors, but I am unsure how to find two vectors in this case.

Comment: Given two points, do you know how to find the vector that goes from one to the other?

Comment: @Arthur I think so. Would the vector from $(a,0,0)$ to $(0,b,0)$ be $(a,-b,0)$?

Comment: Yes, it would (almost; what you have is the vector from $(0,b,0)$ to $(a,0,0)$). That is a vector in $S$, because the start and end points are both in $S$. Can you find another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let: 
$$
\vec A= (a,0,0)^T \qquad \vec B= (0,b,0)^T \qquad \vec C= (0,0,c)^T
$$

take the vectors $\overrightarrow {AB}=\vec B-\vec A$ and $\overrightarrow {AC}=\vec C-\vec A$

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to answer this question if you're not required to use the specified method.

The equation of the plane containing face $S$ is
$$
\frac{1}{a} x +
 \frac{1}{b} y+
\frac{1}{c} z  = 1 .
$$
That means 
$$
\left( 
\frac{1}{a},
 \frac{1}{b},
\frac{1}{c}
\right)
$$
is perpendicular to the plane. Now divide it by its length to normalize it.